# Automation of login is not possible using Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get report from id-pwd required site. This site is showing 2 different login sites randomly (I do not know why, but I am guessing they do not like retrieving data by bot).

Login HTML 1:

```
<div class="login-modal-content">

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/mp/login" class="signin-page-form" name="sign-in-form" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="field email-field fade-label">
            <label class="text" for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus" class="text" id="email" name="email" size="30" spellcheck="false" type="email" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="message-box-error-wrapper">
            <div class="message-box-error"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="field password-field fade-label">
            <label class="text" for="password">Password</label>
            <input class="text" id="password" name="password" size="30" autocomplete="off" type="password" value="">
            <div class="login-forgot-password-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="forgot-password-link track-event">Forgot Password</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>

        <div id="captcha" class="g-recaptcha submit-button"></div>

        <div class="submit-button full-length-submit-button">
            <button id="sign-in-button" name="sign-in-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-blue track-event">
                <span class="button-text">Sign In</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            Don’t have a ---- account?
            <span class="signup-today">
                <a href="-----------------------" class="track-event">Sign up</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Login HTML 2.

```
<main class="layout-base__body">
    
    <h1 data-test-heading="">Sign in</h1>
    <p data-test-subheading="">
        New to Square? <market-link href="/signup?country_code=us&amp;lang_code=en" hydrated="">Sign up</market-link>
    </p>

    <form data-test-form="" name="sign-in-form">

        <market-field data-test-email-field="" hydrated="">
            <market-input-text data-test-email-input="" name="email" input-id="email" autocomplete="username" type="email" value="" hydrated="" class="">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            </market-input-text>
        <!---->  
        </market-field>

        <market-field data-test-password-field="" hydrated="">
            <market-input-password data-test-password-input="" name="password" type="password" hydrated="">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            </market-input-password>
        <!---->  
        </market-field>

        <p>
            <div>            
                <market-link data-test-forgot-password="" id="login-standard-forgot-password-link" href="#" hydrated="">
                    Forgot password?
                </market-link>                
            </div>
        </p>
        <!---->  
        <div>            
            <market-button data-test-submit="" id="login-standard-submit" name="sign-in-button" rank="primary" role="button" type="button" variant="regular" size="medium" hydrated="">
            Sign in
            </market-button>            
        </div>
    </form>  
</main>
```

Here is my partial code for login.

```
def find_single_name(browser, timeout, el_name):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.NAME, el_name)
            )
        )
        element = browser.find_element(By.NAME, el_name)
        return element
        
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"Could not find element ID of {el_name}")
        return None

###########
login_id = find_single_name(browser=browser, timeout=60, el_name='email')
login_id.click()
login_id.clear()
login_id.send_keys(id)
time.sleep(1)

login_pwd = find_single_name(
    browser=browser, timeout=60, el_name='password')
login_pwd.click()
login_pwd.clear()
login_pwd.send_keys(pwd)
time.sleep(1)

login_btn = find_single_name(
    browser=browser, timeout=60, el_name='sign-in-button')
login_btn.click()
time.sleep(timeout)
```

When I happened to get login HTML 1 page, no problem to sign in and download all the reports I need, but same code is not working on login HTML 2. browser closed in no time on login 2 HTML.

I am struggling with this problem for weeks and gave up to solve this issue. Please advise me. I am praying not to deal with login 2 HTML whenever scraping that site...

Comment: can you share a link to the page you are trying to login? Is that twitter?

Comment: It's square POS site.